# How to monitor a c# program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, monitor, antivirus

I have a simple c# program (fw 4.5 developed with vs2015).
The program uses few forms, basic controls and windows media player api.

When I run the program from the vs2015 (by hitting F5) it runs fine.
When I try to run it from the file system (By going to the "release" directory under my project directory) by double clicking it, it just loads and loads but nothing happens. I get no error and the program does not start to run.

I have a try/catch in the start thet should popup a message or write to log file but still I get nothing.

Is there a way to monitor my program to check where it fails or what it`s trying to do that crash it?

(I tried compatebility mode, didn't work).

--EDIT--
I have Avira anti virus install on that computer

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe check your Task Manager and see if the program is running there? Also, ensure that the correct project in your solution is being outputted.

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus temporarily?

Comment: did u try to look at windows event viewer?

Comment: Try running the program from 'debug' folder instead of 'release' folder

Comment: @Martheen! You were right! Its seem that my Avast A/V blocked it. I don't know why but when I disabled it, My program run. Thanks alot!

Comment: @ZoRo This seems to be related to Avast sandboxing feature, which theoretically can happen on other anti-malware suite. If you edit your question to mention avast and generalize it (since the problem purely depend on Avast, not VS or .Net Framework), you can write your own answer about disabling avast. Then other user can link to your question as semi-canonical for trouble with Avast (saw the same scenario several times elsewhere lately, but never happened to mine, so this seems to be case-by-case basis)

Answer (score 1):

In you Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    ....
}
```

and add static method to log an exception

```
    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.Error(.....);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Thanks to @Martheen idea, I tried disabling my anti virus (I have Avira) and it seem to work.

I don't know why it was blocked and Avira did not inform me about the blocking but after disabling Avira, my program run smooth. When enabling Avira again, My program stoped running. After tring this a few time with both debug and release versions, I can confirm that disabling Avira (Right click on Avira icon in taskbar, Choose "Disable") fix my problem.